# Wordpress PHP - How to update plugin setting value in main file

Tags: php, variables, wordpress

This is from inside my Wordpress plugin, inside the main file:

```
function my_plugin_install() {

    $my_site_url = get_site_url();

    $my_options['my_site_url'] = $my_site_url;

    // Save

}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_install');
```

Currently, the install is successful but the 'my_site_url' option is not saved. I'm assuming because the way I'm using the $my_options array at this point doesn't mean anything. It should save this data to the wp_options table.

I can't seem to get this to save, or even find a way to test this as using "echo" gives Wordpress an error during install. Is there a best method for running a script and updating the database during install?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the WordPress function [update_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) to save your option value:

```
function my_plugin_install() {
    $my_site_url = get_site_url();
    update_option('my_site_url', $my_site_url);
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_install');
```

And then later, when you need that value, you can use [get_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option):

```
$my_site_url = get_option('my_site_url');
```

***UPDATE**
Since it appears you want to manage **multiple** of your own options, then I suggest using a simple "utility" function, like so:

```
function update_my_option($key, $value) {  
    // Load all of the option values from wp_options
    $all_options = get_option('my_options');
    // Update just the one option you passed in
    $all_options[$key] = $value;
    // Save to wp_options
    update_option('my_options');
}
```

And, an appropriate getter function:

```
function get_my_option($key, $default = NULL) {
    // Load all of your options from wp_options
    $all_options = get_option('my_options');
    // Return just the one option you are asking for
    return (isset($all_options[$key])) ? $all_options[$key] : $default;
}
```

Then, rather than calling `update_option` directly, you'll call this function, as illustrated below:

```
function my_plugin_install() {
    $my_site_url = get_site_url();
    update_my_option('my_site_url', $my_site_url);
}
```

And, to get one of your options:

```
$my_site_url = get_my_option('my_site_url');
```

Comment: Thanks, update_option looks like exactly what I need to be using! Do you know how I can use this code to specify my particular option to update? Have tried this, but currently failing: update_option('my_options[my_site_url]', $my_site_url);

Comment: I've provided an update to the answer to give you exactly this.  (I use this sort of thing often).